# angular how to output content line by line

Tags: angularjs

I want to output my logs line by line with a short delay, my code is like

```
    log "xxxxxx", 300  //output this log and delay 300ms to output next
    log "xxxxxx", 2000
    log "xxxxxx" ...
    log "xxxxxx"
    log "xxxxxx"

    function log(content, last){
      exitTime = last + new Date().getTime()
      while(true) {
        if ((new Date()).getTime() > exitTime){
          break;
        }
      }
      $socpe.logs.push content
    }
```

and my html

```
<div ng-repeat="log in logs track by $index">{{log}}</div>
```

But it doesn't work to output line by line, I've tried using `$timeout` when `$socpe.logs.push content` but still not work,  so how make it work?

Comment: How about using an array in the view model, outputting it with an ng-repeat in the view, and populating the array with a timeout?

Comment: i will highly suggest use timer instead of using above logic to add delay.

Comment: timeout will cause many recursion, I would like to figure out ways to write like my mockup